# Difference between I18n.t and t in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, yaml

I have a strange problem. I have en.yml file that looks like this:

```
en:
  no_notifiaction: No Notification 
  active_notification: Active notification


t('.active_notification') == "Active notification" #false
I18n.t('.active_notification') == "Active notification" #true?
```

Why is that?

Comment: What does `t` return?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#looking-up-translations) under "Lazy Lookups". `t('.active_notification')` is only available within the corresponding view and controller. Not if you call it, let's say in a javascript file or any other view...

Comment: this is not what the documentation refers to as "lazy lookup". Lazy lookup refers to accessing the literal using the `.active_notification` key instead of the full key. The question is about using `I18n.t` or `t`

Comment: In fact, the answer is in the same documentation but different part: *Rails adds a t (translate) helper method to your views so that you do not need to spell out I18n.t all the time*